# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.MapLookup.toMap

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to deploy a WAR file to a Glassfish 4.1 server.

During an attempt at deployment, I receive the following exception :

> java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.MapLookup.toMap(Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/Map;

Looking in the javadoc, I indeed can't see any toMap method ? (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/MapLookup.html)

jar tvf on the war file :

```
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/javax.inject-2.4.0-b06.jar
WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar
WEB-INF/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jersey-common-2.15.jar
WEB-INF/lib/hk2-api-2.4.0-b06.jar
WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.15.jar
WEB-INF/lib/hk2-locator-2.4.0-b06.jar
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-web-2.0.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.0.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jersey-client-2.15.jar
WEB-INF/lib/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b06.jar
WEB-INF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b06.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.0.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jersey-guava-2.15.jar
WEB-INF/lib/jersey-server-2.15.jar
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-web-2.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>WebTool</groupId>
<artifactId>WebTool</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>WebTool</name>

<build>
    <finalName>WebTool</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- my -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commonslang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${commonscodec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end my -->
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    -->



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${postgresql.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${log4j.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${log4j.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${log4j.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${commonslang.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${commonscodec.version}</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- configure connection pool in glassfish admin ! JDBC Connection Pool and JCBC Resource -->
</dependencies>
<!--
   DEPENDENCY MANAGEMENT
   -->

<properties>
    <postgresql.version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
    <jersey.version>2.15</jersey.version>
    <log4j.version>2.1</log4j.version>
    <dbcp2.version>2.0.1</dbcp2.version>
    <commonslang.version>3.3.2</commonslang.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <commonscodec.version>1.10</commonscodec.version>
</properties>
```

Dependency tree:

```
    [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ WebTool ---
[INFO] WebTool:WebTool:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.15:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.15:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.3-1102-jdbc41:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
```

Comment: You have multiple versions of log4j version 2 in your deployment.  Only use one.

Comment: But how ?? As you can see, my pom.xml only defines once.  I thought the whole point of dependencyManagement was to fix clashes ?

Comment: You need to find out why both these are present: "WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.0.2.jar"

Comment: Well 2.1 is there because I asked for it.  I've absolutley no idea where 2.0.2 is coming from, as you can see.. I have not requested 2.0.2 in my pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple versions of log4j version 2 in your WAR file, one you specified, and one - most likely - pulled in as a transitive dependency.  Normally only the latest should be selected, but it may be a repackaged version.

Hence you need to identify where the one you do not want, comes from so you can figure out what to do with it.  You can see the dependency tree with

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html for usage information.

Note that if you use Eclipse with m2e, just select the correct panel when having pom.xml open.

You then need to figure out what to do with it when you find out where it comes from.  You most likely just want to exclude it (as you have a newer) - see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html for instructions.  I would suggest you read it carefully so you understand what you are doing - this is essentially brain washing Maven because you know better.

Comment: I have updated my original post with my dependency tree.  As you can see, no 2.0.2 there either ?!?

Comment: Do you ever run "mvn clean"?

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA, and so "Invalidate caches" and "Rebuild project" has the same effect I believe.

Comment: Answer has been awarded to you, not for the main answer but for "mvn clean". It seems "invalidate caches" and "rebuild project" in Intellij doesn't quite go as far as it should !

Comment: When using maven, you should always verify the build process outside of your IDE in case of problems.